# Search in a string and split the original string by the found content

Tags: c#, string, split

I'm wondering if there is a good way to find content, and also split the results by the found content, for example if I have string:

```
string str = "you androids don't exactly cover for each other in times of stress. 
i think you're right it would seem we lack a specific talent you humans possess
i believe it's called empathy";
```

and the search strings, for example:

```
var sList = new List {"for each other",  "talent", "you humans"};
```

The result with the found strings separated by spitting of the original string would be:

```
you androids don't exactly cover 
for each other 
in times of stress. i think you're right it would seem we lack a specific 
talent 
you humans  
possess i believe it's called empathy
```

In case the same string is in two different search strings (here it *you*):

```
var sList = new List {"for each other", "other in", "talent", "you humans", "you"};
```

The correct output should be this:

```
you 
androids don't exactly cover 
for each other
other in
times of stress. i think you're right it would seem we lack a specific 
talent 
you
you humans  
possess i believe it's called empathy
```

Comment: Not sure how you'll do the second where you duplicate content but the first one should be possible by using `Regex.Split`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to match a set of strings within a string, and then you need to account for gaps in between, adjusting for overlapping matched ranges:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = "you androids don't exactly cover for each other in times of stress. i think youre right it would seem we lack a specific talent you humans possess i believe it's called empathy"; 
        var sList = new List<string> {"for each other", "other in", "talent", "you humans", "you"};
        var chRangeMap = new bool[str.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < chRangeMap.Length; ++i) chRangeMap[i] = false;

        var matchedTokenMap = sList
            .Select(i => "\\b" + Regex.Escape(i) + "\\b")
            .SelectMany(p => (new Regex(p)).Matches(str).OfType<Match>())
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => new 
                    { 
                        StartIndex = m.Index,
                        EndIndex = m.Index + m.Length,
                        Length = m.Length
                    })
            .Select(r => {
                for (var i = r.StartIndex; i < r.EndIndex; ++i) chRangeMap[i] = true;
                return r;
                });

        var fullTokenized = 
            matchedTokenMap.Concat(
                GetArrayRanges(chRangeMap, false)
                    .Select(r => new 
                            { 
                                StartIndex = r.Item1,
                                EndIndex = r.Item2,
                                Length = r.Item2 - r.Item1
                            })
            )
            .OrderBy(k => k.StartIndex).ThenBy(sk => sk.Length);

        foreach(var token in fullTokenized)
        {
            WriteTrimmed(str.Substring(token.StartIndex, token.Length));
        }
    }

    private static void WriteTrimmed(string str)
    {
        str = str.Trim();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> GetArrayRanges(bool[] array, bool seekValue)
    {
        int? rangeStart = null;

        for(var i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (array[i] == seekValue)
            {
                if (!rangeStart.HasValue)
                {
                    rangeStart = i;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (rangeStart.HasValue)
                {
                    yield return Tuple.Create(rangeStart.Value, i);
                    rangeStart = null;
                }
            }
        }

        if (rangeStart.HasValue)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(rangeStart.Value, array.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

[DotNETFiddle of the code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KQx2rN).

Comment: Better to use `Regex.Escape` to escape all potential special characters.

Comment: @juharr You're absolutely correct.  I updated for that one.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: LB2 Hello, this is useful solution, except results in case of same value in separate  searching strings

Comment: @dimAB, not sure I understand what you mean by _"same value in separate searching strings"_. Please clarify

Comment: @LB2 yes, sure. you have to check  `var sList = new List<string> {"for each other", "other in", "talent", "you humans", "you"};` to see what I mean, same way as solution by degant also does not match the desired output

Comment: @dimAB, I'm assuming you're referring to the case where `youre` gets split into `you` and `re` - i.e. not at the word boundary?

Comment: @dimAB, Ok, I think I understand better now.  It's not ust `youre` getting split, but that there is also overlap in matches, and you want to extract every match including overlaps, and then any section that didn't result in any match?

Comment: @dimAB, Updated here and in the fiddle.  I believe this now does how you want it.  It can probably be improved and made more efficient, but algorithmically it should be what you're looking for.

Comment: @LB2 Impressive and exactly answers the question I've asked!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<string> parts = new List<string> { str };
sList.ForEach(seperator => parts = parts
    .SelectMany(part => Regex.Match(part, "(.*) ?(\\b" + seperator + "\\b) ?(.*)|(.+)")
        .Groups
        .Cast<Group>()
        .Where(group => group.Success)
        .Select(group => group.Value)
        .Skip(1))
    .ToList());

parts = parts
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
    .ToList();
```

Output:

```
you
androids don't exactly cover 
for each other
in times of stress. i think youre right it would seem we lack a specific 
talent
you
humans
possess i believe it's called empathy
```

[Dotnet Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jRIIMi)

Comment: your output does not match the expected output, where there is an extra "you" in the second-to-last entry. :p

Comment: @RufusL that is actually correct because `you humans` will actually be broken down into `you` + `humans` since `you` is part of the list to split using i.e `sList`. OP should confirm the same

Comment: Haha, I know, it's a bug in the expected output, not your code. Hence the smiley face at the end of my comment...

Comment: aaah, my bad, didn't notice :D

Comment: @Rufus L yes you are right! First it seemed to me that the second condition was being fulfilled correctly.  my bad. I'm going to remove answer mark from solution, it is good but does not match the expected output same as LB2 answer.

Comment: @dimAB Verify your expected output again, the sub-part `you humans` will be broken down into `you` + `humans` because your `sList[4]` is `you`. Isn't that correct?

Comment: @degant yes but  I'm trying to get all listed value as separately exist in string, so if I have listed "you", "you humans" i want get each as separate string and in sequence, exactly as it is shown in my  second example

Comment: You really should have all code in the answer in addition to the link to fiddle.